# Visual Studio C# unit testing - report results for each run

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Is there way to automate reporting of each test run?

Now I do this

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
   ReportTestStarted("Test1");
   // do test like 
   Assert.IsTrue(true,"Fake good test");
   ReportTestFinshed("Test1");
}
```

with assumption that when test started it should be finished then it is good. ReportTest*() collects all results and then stores them somehow.

I hope that it is possible to use Attributes and update [TestMethod] so it will do such work automatically.
Any ideas?

Update: Thanks for @Richard's and @Scott hints I had figured out that I can use this code and know result based on this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.unittestoutcome.aspx)

```
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
       [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanupTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "TextContext.TestName='{0}' {1} ",
                TestContext.TestName,
(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.UnitTestOutcome.Passed==TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome?"Pass":"Fail"));
        }
```

Comment: One option is to build the test function such that it writes the results along the way to a file or database which you can then check after it is finished to see the outputs at the different stages. Another method would be to write the test method to activate functions and check if the output is as desired.

Comment: I sugest looking deeper into microsofts unit test library or getting NUnit from Nuget and using that. You should also be using contracts in your test code to make sure your code runs as expected.

Comment: Debug.WriteLine is great except who will read it? And I still have to add it to the tests. It means thousands of extra lines to the thousands of tests.

Comment: For the last sentance of your update, did you look at all the properties of TestContext? There is a [`CurrentTestOutcome`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.currenttestoutcome.aspx) property.

Comment: If you answered your own question post an answer and accept it in two days. Also, do you really consider a skipped or inconclusive test failed? Personally I would have done `TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for comments I have my answer:

```
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
       [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanupTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "TextContext.TestName='{0}' {1} ",
                TestContext.TestName,
(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.UnitTestOutcome.Passed==TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome?"Pass":"Fail"));
        }
```

It provides access to the test name and test result which I can use and store in any way. Most important - I do not have to touch my TestMethods. This approach collects and reports all result without adding extra lines of code to each TestMethod.